# How to create char[][] from txt file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, text-files

I am pretty new to C and I have got a problem here in C:
I want to write a program which reads a txt file and writes the content it a `char[50][50]`.

To read the file I used `fopen` but I have no idea how to write this into the array. What is a good way to solve this?

Comment: What does the file look like ? What defines a "row" ?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: The txt is randomly filled with "X", it should define a start point later. I tried nothing, just asked google, because i am not familiar with c yet.

Comment: If you are not familiar with a programming language, the only way to learn it is to CODE! You can read 10 books, and still not be able to make the most simple program. You'll make mistakes, but that doesn't matter, you learn from them. Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but somewhere you have to start and I stuck at this point and don't know how to get further.

Comment: @hidde Nothing comes from nothing, so an intial read is not really a bad idea!

Comment: Starting here is a good idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language

Comment: Forgot to mentiond that if you are going to show interest in the book mentioned above turn to the 2nd edition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: @BLUEPIXY's answer is significantly better than this approach.

@Hidde's code adapted for this specific example:

```
// Include the standard input / output files.
// We'll need these for opening our file
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{
    // A pointer to point to the memory containing the file data:
    FILE * pFile;

    // Open the file itself:
    pFile=fopen ("250.txt","r");
    // Check that we opened the file successfully:
    if (pFile==NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error opening file");
    }
    else
    {
        // The file is open so we can read its contents.
        // Lets just assume its got 50*50=250 chars in.

        // Initialise an array to hold our results:
        char array[50][50];
        int row, col;
        for (row = 0; row < 50; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 50; col++)
            {
                // Store the next char from our file in our array:
                array[row][col] = fgetc (pFile);
            }
        }

        // Close the file
        fclose (pFile);

        // Demonstrate that we've succeeded:
        for (row = 0; row < 50; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 50; col++)
            {
                printf("%c", array[row][col]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    // Return 0 indictaes success
    return 0;
}
```

Really there should be some code to check that the input file meets your expectations, otherwise strange things may happen.

Comment: This looks interesting, I going to take a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to use fread if it only read from a file the size of the specific.
E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char data[50][50];
    int count;

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen("data.txt","r"))){
        perror("file not open\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    count=fread(&data[0][0], sizeof(char), 50*50, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    {   //input check
        int i;
        char *p = &data[0][0];
        for(i=0;i<count;++i)
            putchar(*p++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 50*50 replace sizeof(data) or sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* fgetc example: money counter */
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  int c;
  int n = 0;
  pFile=fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
  if (pFile==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
  else
  {
    do {
      c = fgetc (pFile);
      if (c == '$') n++;
    } while (c != EOF);
    fclose (pFile);
    printf ("The file contains %d dollar sign characters ($).\n",n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Copied from [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/). You can read the file using `fgetc(FILE* )`. You make a while loop, in which you test if the last character read is not the end of the file. I hope you can fill your array with this code.

Comment: @Corbin `getc` and `fgetc` are the  most flexible mechanisms to portably read files in C.

Comment: @cnicutar Yeah, but how often do people really want to read one character at a time?  That just sounds painful.  (Though I suppose a 50x50 array does imply that character reading may actually be appropriate.)

Comment: Isn't that why I gave this as an answer? Ofcourse there are other ways, but I think in this situation `fgetc()` will work best.

Comment: @Hidde to be honest, I assumed you wrote it because it was easy to copy and paste.  Though it could be adapter for the right thing, it shows how to count a specific character, not how to store a file into an array.  Guess I should not have made that assumption :)

Comment: I could also have copied the `fgets()` code. I am not going to write his entire program, I just wanted to give him a push in the right direction, by showing some code, which he probably couldn't find himself. He'll ofcourse have to write his own program to finish his assignment.